# Перевести число дней в месяцы

Tags: c#, datetime

Добрий день.

Нужно перевести определенное количество дней в месяца.

Как лучше это сделать?

Делаю так :

```
months = ((tillDate.Value.Year * 12 + tillDate.Value.Month) -
          (fromDate.Year * 12 + fromDate.Month));
```

Но не совсем понимаю зачем год умножать на 12 (`tillDate.Value.Year * 12`) ?

Спасибо.

Comment: А кто мешает упростить и сначала вычислить разность в годах, а потом уже считать количество месяцев, прибавляя разницу между tillDate.Value.Month и fromDate.Value.Month ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы не можете перевести в месяца абстрактное количество дней, так как месяцы имеют переменную длину. Как совершенно верно делает ваш код, вам нужна начальная и конечная даты.

Теперь, вы не можете просто вычесть номера месяцев от начала года, так как начальная и конечная даты могут отличаться на несколько лет!

Поэтому используется такой простой алгоритм: вычисляем глобальный номер месяца начиная от 0-го года для начальной и конечной дат, вычитаем их — это и будет разница в месяцах. Именно это и делает ваш код: `tillDate.Value.Year * 12` — количество месяцев за предыдущие годы, `tillDate.Value.Month` — количество месяцев за последний год.

Читайте код так:

```
int till_GlobalNumberOfMonth = tillDate.Value.Year * 12 + tillDate.Value.Month;
int from_GlobalNumberOfMonth = fromDate.Year * 12 + fromDate.Month;

months = till_GlobalNumberOfMonth - from_GlobalNumberOfMonth;
```

Answer (score 2):

Вопрос не совсем корректный. От какого месяца считать? У нас бывает и 31 день, и 30, и даже 28.

А так, возьмите за константу, допустим, 30 дней. (Хоть это совершенно неправильно). И количество дней делите на константу. Пример, 90 дней делим на 30 = 3 месяца.

UPDATE:

Вы код выложили после моего ответа.
Тогда наиболее корректный вариант:

```
var Months = Math.Truncate((Days % 365) / 30);
```

Comment: (731%365) = 1;

1/30 = 0.33;

Math.Truncate(0.33) = 0

это не 24 месяца. увы((

Comment: К сожалению, работает до 365 дней. Чтобы заработало, узнайте сколько лет прошло.